# Angular 9 error building library in the node_modules folder

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, package, ng-packagr

When the project folder is named root_project everything works fine

```
root_project
└── projects
    └── my-lib
```

but if I change the folder name to node_modules

```
node_modules
└── projects
    └── my-lib
```

I get the next error:

```
Building Angular Package
******************************************************************************
It is not recommended to publish Ivy libraries to NPM repositories.
Read more here: https://v9.angular.io/guide/ivy#maintaining-library-compatibility
******************************************************************************

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Building entry point 'my-lib'
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Compiling TypeScript sources through ngc
Bundling to FESM2015
ERROR: Could not resolve './lib' from dist/my-lib/esm2015/public-api.js
An unhandled exception occurred: Could not resolve './lib' from dist/my-lib/esm2015/public-api.js
See "/tmp/ng-WPQygP/angular-errors.log" for further details.
```